# How to mount SRAM snaplock?

Tags: chain, sram

I am trying to join PC-1 SRAM chain, it has such snaplock:

[image]

And the problem is, the distance between holes is slightly less (IMHO) than distance between the pins. Every hole on its own fits any pin, but so far I am unable to put the golden part onto the pins, either one holes fit, or the other -- and I cannot make them both snap at the same time.

I have manual for this chain, but irony, it describes how to use silver power lock (asymmetric), not this one.

So, how to mount it? Should I use tools like pliers?

Comment: I run a Rohloff on my bike and this is the first time using this kind of chain... THANK YOU FOR THIS INSTALLATION TIP!!! I was going nuts :)

Comment: Thanks, this was a life saver, I was about to resort to the "Hammer" The dumbest tool in the box...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put link into chain, hold chain on either side, use thumbs to hold snaplock over link. *Gently* pull chain using thumbs as fulcrums...this will put pressure on the pins forcing them just a tiny bit inward. Snaplock should slide over. (Think of it kind of like bending but not breaking a pencil...both hands on pencil (chain), thumbs next to each other, gentle pressure.

Comment: Oh boy! And btw. for second time with chain, I missed the rigid axis of the chain, and initially I tried to rather squeeze it :-( Anyway, it worked, thank you very, very, much!

Comment: @greenoldman Confused the heck out of me first time too!

Comment: I am having absolutely no luck installing the snap lock. My hands are now killing me and I'm no closer. Is there any other way?

Comment: Good answer - but for completeness, how do you get it off again?

Comment: Getting it back off - I usually use a thick pick, but screwdriver will work as well...slide tool in the gap with snaplock towards you, take chain in both hands a link or three to the left and right of lock. Use thumb from one hand to put pressure on tool while gently applying pressure with each hand (again, bending the pencil, not breaking it)...your pinkies should come toward you and in.